# Using React-native, do not get data from the firebase

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a cross-platform application using React. I found some examples of how to get data from the firebase. Here is the code I wrote:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   authDomain: "<xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com>",
   databaseURL: "<https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com>",
   storageBucket: "<xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com>",
 };

  var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(fireBaseconfig);
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var ref = rootRef.child("items");
  ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot);
  });
```

But taking advantage of the breakpoint, at the time of debugging, I noticed that the callback does not play and data does not come from the firebase. My application just does not go to the block at this location:

```
console.log(snapshot);
```

Tell me what I'm doing is not right?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a very efficient interactive debugging tool. The first step might be to also handle security errors by adding `.catch(function(error) { console.error(error); })` in addition to your `then()`.

Comment: I understand this is a function to detect errors in queries. Can you show how the complete line of this code should look like? My application does not run with her

Comment: `ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot);
  }).catch(function(error) { console.error(error); });`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I get such data in the console:  `Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}`. I suspect that I do not have permission to read data from the database, because the authorization of the user works and then I can not get any data. Not call a callback with a snapshot...

Comment: I figured out the problem, finally. I did not have the correct form of the firevaseConfig. In the fields were written triangular brackets. <>, authDomain: "<xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com>"... Thank you for your responses!